# WEB SOCKET CONFIG NOT SHOW IN AZURE WEB APP

Tags: node.js, azure, websocket, socket.io, azure-web-app-service

I am real time app using node and socket.io. And I deploy it to Azure web app, I have researched and find how to enable web socket in azure web app. It is enable 'Web sockets' in Configuration in Azure Portal. But I cannot see 'Web sockets' config.

**My question is:**

It is error?

Or How I can enable socket in Azure Web App?

**Here is image of my configuration:**

*(it must be have Web Sockets tag)*

[image]

**It must be:**
[image]

Comment: Please include your configuration and code as text and not as linked documents, as these links would tend to expire some time in the future and therefore cannot be accessed, which would make this question without context.

Comment: I use azure service in VS code, how I check configuration as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have created the Azure Web App in Linux OS, then you'll not get the Option of enabling Web Socket in Platform settings:

[image]

If the Azure Web App is created in Windows OS Hosting plan, then the Web Socket option is enabled under the Configuration of App Service > Platform Settings:

[image]

Comment: So in Linux OS, how I can enable socket

Comment: To get that enabling web socket option, you have to deploy your web-app in Linux OS Plan.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across with the same issue - whilst the documentation says that it is enabled by default in Linux, I found that wasn't true in my case. At which point you'll want to enable it via Azure CLI with the following command

```
 az webapp config set --web-sockets-enabled true --name [app service name] --resource-group [app service resource group]
```